# Can someone help me understand why this is happening?

Tags: javascript, html

I just run into the weirdest thing I've ever encounter.

Consider this test page:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script language=javascript>
        function test(myParameter) {
            alert(myParameter);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" value="Strange" onclick="javascript: test(044024);" />
    <input type="button" value="Ok" onclick="javascript: test('044024');" />
</body>
</html>
```

If I click the "strange" button, I get **18452**, if I click the "ok" button I get **044024**

Does anyone know what is happening and explain it to me?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Javascript is interpreting the symbol 044024 as an octal value because of the leading 0.

044024 oct to dec is 18452

Comment: This "feature" is being removed soon. Thank god. What a horrible decision by someone.

Comment: It's for compatibility with C, Java, and most other C-derived languages. By removing octal numbers, you'd confuse most of the programmers from the C/Java world. :-P

Comment: @d03boy: As far as I understand it, leading zeroes can only be there because of either a deliberate decision, or sloppy code generation. It can't happen by accident, really, so I guess I would not classify it as "horrible design failure".

Comment: @Tomalak, in this case they were internal codes of a legacy system we are migrating... I guess you could call that a deliberate sloppy decision :)

Comment: Just to point out for those who don't see quotes: The number in the OK button is a string.

Answer (score 6):

Numbers prefixed with 0 are considered to be in octal (base 8)

Answer (score 3):

When you write a number with 0 as its first digit, it's an octal number.